# Getting Height of Scaffold's Bottom Navigation Bar in Flutter

Tags: flutter

How can I get the `height` of the `BottomNavigationBar` of a `Scaffold` in Flutter? I know there is `MediaQuery.of(context).size` to get a screen size. Is there a similar method for `BottomNavigationBar`?

Answer (score 23):

```
Container(
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
   height: kBottomNavigationBarHeight,
   child: Scaffold(
       backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
       body: null,
       bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar()
  )
)
```

This will create a Scaffold with enough room only for the BottomNavigationBar widget.

kBottomNavigationBarHeight is a constant, and can be found in the constants.dart file.

Comment: `kBottomNavigationBarHeight` is a constant, but this doesn't take into account the potential for `SafeArea` padding related to iPhones without a home button or Androids using the latest navigation bar.

Answer (score 12):

For getting size of widget you can use `key` field

```
final key = GlobalKey();
... set key field of widget
double height = key.currentContext.size.height;
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to know height of bottomNavigationBar in one of the children's screens of main Scaffold with bottomNavigationBar you can use MediaQuery:

```
final bottomPadding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom;
```

Bottom padding from MediaQuery, in addition of SafeArea, takes into account bottomNavigationBar's height.

More detailed:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final bottomPadding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom; // From here you will get only SafeArea padding.

    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        children: const [

          // But in build() method of each of these screens you will get
          // SafeArea padding with bottomNavigationBar height
          // just by calling MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom;

          FirstScreen(), 
          SecondScreen(),
          ThirdScreen(),
          FourthScreen(),

        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: MyBottomNavigationBar(),
    );
  }
```

Comment: This returned 0 for me, while I had a bottom `BottomNavigationBar`. Not a solution for me.

Comment: So I guess you did something wrong. You did something differently from the way I wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried and for android i used `kBottomNavigationBarHeight` and for ios i think the height is `90 pixel`.. so i declared the height in my constant file such as `double btmNavigationBarHeight = Platform.isAndroid ? kBottomNavigationBarHeight : 90;`

Answer (score 1):

According to dosc: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationBar/height.html

> If null, NavigationBarThemeData.height is used. If that is also null, the default is 80

Comment: In code: `final height = NavigationBarThemeData().height ?? 80`